# How to pass storageaccount key to a Linux VM?

Tags: python, linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template that creates a VM and some storage and in my VSTS Release process I then run a setup script that is stored in source control that installs a Python service on the Linux VM; all these from build artifacts. This all works great however the service needs to read a queue on the storage account created as part of the ARM template.

I'm aware of the ListKeys function in the templates but unsure how I might use that to somehow pass that information to the Linux VM so I can update the Python's scripts config file.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right, you could use [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript) to achieve your need. You could write a script to receive storage account name and storage account key. You could write a script like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
accountname=$1
accountkey=$2
...............
```

You could use the following script to get storage key and pass to your script.

```
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', variables('extensionName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": "[split(parameters('fileUris'), ' ')]",
           "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh ', parameters('scriptName'), ' ' ,parameters('StorageAccountName''), ' ', listKeys(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('StorageAccountName')), 
        },

      }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I was thinking about that but was trying to work out how I get the Script Extension to use a file that is under source control. In the release process on VSTS I could add a task to copy a script to the storage but I'd need to create the storage first in one template and then copy the script and then have the VM template separate so by the time it runs the VM template the script will exist on Azure storage having come from source control initially.

Comment: @Simon Do you mean you want to copy the script from source control to the private storage account by using template? Only use template, based on my knowledge, it is not possible. Use custom script extension, this is possible. copy your script to a VHD. You could check this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-image-new-storage-account/azuredeploy.json#L257).

Comment: Yes and I've worked out that's not possible so think I will have to have tasks - a) deploy a template containing the storage only, b) copy script artifact to storage, c) deploy a template with the VM in and a script extension that references what was created by a and b, assuming I can include/reference the earlier storage details in the VM tempalte...time to experiment!

Comment: @Simon Yes, I think you could do it step by step. It is more easily. Use template to create storage account and VM, you could use template to list storage account key and output. Use Azure PowerShell or Azcopy to upload file to storage account. I think you could do them with a PS file automation.

Comment: Yeah appears I'm going to need to roll my own a bit here, thanks for your input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149096/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-simon).

Comment: I did via a step by step process which when I get time I'll try and add as a proper answer as it took me a number of trial and error attempts so would hope to save others the effort!